# How to use django-filter to make a filter with reverse foreign key value?

Tags: django, search, django-filter

I have a models

```
class TDebtor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    iin = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    alive = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


class TDebtData(models.Model):
    agr_num = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    id_num = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    loan_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    principal_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    id_debtor = models.ForeignKey('TDebtor', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="debtor_debt_data")



views.py

class ProductList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = TDebtor.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('debtor_debt_data', queryset=TDebtData.objects.select_related('id_debtor')))
    for i in queryset:
        print(i.debtor_debt_data.agr_num)
    serializer_class = TDebtorSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['iin', 'first_name', 'surname', 'middle_name', 'birth_date',
                        'alive']
```

if I'll make a filter with the fields of TDebtor it's okay, but how I can filter with agr_num?, I mean if I'll send agr_num=1238HFD32 it will return me TDebtor that has this agr_num

Answer (score 1):

Use `RELATED_NAME__FIELD`. In your case `debtor_debt_data__agr_num`

```py
class ProductList(ListAPIView):
    ...
    filterset_fields = [..., `debtor_debt_data__agr_num`]
```

Docs in https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html